# vlcj: Screen demux error: Cannot create bitmap

Tags: java, screen, vlc, recording, vlcj

I use vlcj (http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/) to use the vlc libs in Java to record my screen. I am using Win7 and XP (on both platforms the error appears).

I run a telnet server on those platforms which get start and stop message to start and stop screen recording. When several recordings were made there appears the following error:
`screen demux error: Cannot create bitmap`

Then I stop the telnet server and restart it again and it can screen capture again. My question is why does this error message appear and how can I solve it so I don't have to restart the server from time to time? Here is a snippet of the code which starts the recording (sry, I can't provide the whole code of the telnet server):

```
NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("vlc", libvlcPath); //libvlcPath is a String with the specified path
System.setProperty("jna.library.path", libvlcPath);
MediaPlayerFactory factory = new MediaPlayerFactory("--no-video-title-show");
EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = factory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
File videoFile = new File(savePath + fileName + ".mp4");
String[] options = {":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=mp4a}:std{access=file,mux=mp4,dst=" + videoFile + "}", ":screen-fps=5.0"};
mediaPlayer.playMedia("screen://", options);
```

And the code to stop the recording:

```
mediaPlayer.stop();
mediaPlayer.release();
```

I also run the telnet server (the exact same code) on Mac OS and Ubuntu 10.04 and there the error has never appeared. So it has something to do with Windows in general?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should try to display more information about your bug. Use -vvv option to get
a full output for debugging.

Comment: where do you use this -vvv option? is it a VM-argument?

Comment: This is an argument for vlc, not a VM-argument.

Comment: By the way, there is a JVM argument "-Dvlcj.log=DEBUG" to enable more output.

Comment: Do you mean: `String[] options = {":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=mp4a}:std{access=file,mux=mp4,dst=" + videoFile + "}", ":screen-fps=5.0", ":vvv};` This doesn't result in any effect. where exactly do I have to put it in my code? thanks so far.

Comment: Currently not able to test. There is a setLogLevel method on MediaPlayerFactory. Used with LogLevel.DBG, it should provide more debug information.